# Devemos padronizar o uso de sites que auxiliam postagem de código?

Tags: debate, postagem

Normalmente estamos vendo todos usar o [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) e o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) para testar e ajudar entender códigos postados aqui no site. Todo mundo acaba se acostumando com eles.

Mas existem outros sites concorrentes que também podem ser usados. E nem estou falando de outras linguagens.

Manter um padrão, ou seja, ter que postar sempre no mesmo site facilita para tomo mundo lidar com o mesmo site e não ter que aprender a usar um novo site que outra pessoa gosta mais.

Por outro lado, essa pessoa pode não estar confortável com os sites que foram padronizados aqui.

Certamente o lucro de um será o prejuízo de outro e vice-versa. Não tem como ser perfeito.

Devemos padronizar a mesma ferramenta para todos e não aceitar outros sites?

Quem colocar um site diferente do padrão, alguém deve copiar para o site padrão e editar o post para ter **também** o código postado no nosso site padrão?

Ou permitir tudo e vamos nos adaptando ao gosto de cada um?

Paralelamente, se for padronizado. Quais deveriam ser esses sites padrão para cada linguagem?

Comment: Ao downvoter, só fiz uma pergunta. Ela não é relevante? Se está expressando discordância, seria do que já que não dei resposta alguma?

Comment: Li a pergunta ontem pelo celular e devo ter apertado na seta enquanto rolava a página sem querer. Só reparei agora que meu voto ficou negativo. E é tarde demais para remover, só com uma edição.. :/

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Sem problemas, shit happens :) Eu precisava fazer edição mesmo.

Comment: Acho que se torna mais uma questão "cultural" do que de padronização. Pra mim o JSFIDDLE serve muito bem, me acostumei com ele, e sempre que possível é ele que eu indico para snippets de código.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não acredito que padronizar algo assim seja necessário, ou possível.

Não vejo necessidade por uma série de motivos:

1. O uso de uma IDE online ou serviço de snippet deve ser apenas complementar, não **fundamental**, ao post. Ter um exemplo bacana e funcional no JSFiddle não substitui a presença de código no próprio post.
2. A maior parte deles é simples o suficiente *para quem visita*. Ir ver um exemplo de código não implica em ter que aprender como o serviço funciona, então não há realmente uma perda de compreensão entre hospedar seu exemplo em um serviço ou outro.
3. Derivando do ponto anterior, não há ganho relevante em qualidade ou usabilidade em se decidir por um serviço padrão.

Quanto à possibilidade de se estabelecer uma regra nesse sentido:

1. É inviável vigiar todos os posts só pra manter a uniformidade.
2. O que fazer se o `serviço padrão` decidir bater as botas?
3. Se fosse obrigatório o uso de um serviço, caberia a quem ensinar todos os usuários a usá-lo, e mantê-los atualizados nas mudanças que ocorrerem?
4. Talvez **hoje** uma maioria decida por usar o JSFiddle. Daqui a 1 ano, a maioria decida que o JSBin é melhor.
5. Impedir alguém de postar porque não ela não usou a *ferramenta externa* correta, é... esquisito.

Comment: Adiciono o cssdeck.com na lista. Uns são melhores em colaboração, outros nas línguas disponíveis: cada um escolha a melhor ferramenta para sua situação. Só não sinto bem quando colocam o código na pergunta: ela fica muito extensa e as vezes desorganizada (HTML misturado com javascript, por exemplo).

Answer (score 6):

A pergunta é interessante, mas a limitação, como já referiste é que para todos trabalharem com o mesmo, será necessário que "metade" aprenda o que venha a ficar definido como padrão.

A minha opinião é deixar como está, ou seja, cada um utiliza e aplica exemplos para o código no site que já conhece/utiliza, e a partir dai:

1. Gostei e aprendo como usar o site novo;
2. Não gostei e na resposta que coloco, o exemplo vai no site que conheço.

A questão aqui é que os ganhos vão ser sempre menores:

Ou andamos a editar *posts* para trocar o site que aloja o exemplo, dando aso a uma edição + trabalho de mover o exemplo para o outro site;
Ou o autor do *post* é informado que está a usar um site *não padrão* e vai fazer o referido em cima.

#### Ganhos

- Uniformização dos sites onde ficam os exemplos de código

#### Problemas

- Mais um motivo para moderar e monitorizar *posts*;
- Mais um nível de edição na pergunta/resposta;
- Passar conteúdo de site A para site B representando trabalho extra;
- Novos utilizadores todos os dias, comentários de alerta todos os dias;
- Para quem não conhece o site *padrão* para exemplo X, terá que aprender algo externo à SE para poder aplicar um exemplo de código na pergunta.

---

O grande ganho que vejo aqui em deixar como está, é que assim não só tomamos conhecimento de novos sites e ferramentas como todos os utilizadores são livres de utilizar o que já conhecem e estão à vontade com, que acaba por ser uma bola de neve, pois todo o utilizador vai acabar por tomar conhecimento de outros sites e ferramentas. Por último mas não menos importante, não existirá um trabalho acrescido de moderação sobre este assunto.

## E uma situação win-win se ficar como está.